# C++ std::function parameters const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, functional-programming

I want to write a function, which could receive a ostream, a iterable object v, and a function op. The function is supposed to call op on every element in v, and then send the result to ostream. So I write the following code:

```
template<typename T,
        typename IN = decltype(*std::declval<T>().begin()),
        typename FT = function<ostream&(ostream&, const IN&)>
        >
void func(ostream& ss, const T& v,
              FT op = [](ostream& os, const IN&v)->ostream&{ return os << v; }) {
    for (const auto& i: v) {
        std::invoke(op, ss, i);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    func(cout, vec);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile these code with clang++, I got following errors.

```
 /mnt/d/codes/stlprinter/stack.cpp:42:9: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke'
        std::invoke(op, ss, i);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/codes/stlprinter/stack.cpp:48:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, int &, std::function<std::basic_ostream<char> &(std::basic_ostream<char> &, int &)>>' requested here
    func(cout, vec);
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/functional:85:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Callable = std::function<std::basic_ostream<char> &(std::basic_ostream<char> &, int &)> &, _Args = <std::basic_ostream<char> &, const int &>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result<std::function<std::basic_ostream<char> &(std::basic_ostream<char> &, int &)> &, std::basic_ostream<char> &, const int &>'
    invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

The error message figures that when call invoke, the type of op is _Callable = std::functionstd::basic_ostream<char &(std::basic_ostream &, int &)> &, but the op is defined by FT = function<ostream&(ostream&, const IN&)>, why the 'const' specifier of the second argument is lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `IN`, i.e. the type `decltype(*std::declval<T>().begin())` is a reference `int&`; then for `const IN&`, `const` is qualified on the reference and just gets ignored. So given `IN` is `int&`, `const IN&` -> `int& &` -> `int&`.

See the behavior of [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> 1. ...
> 2. If the argument is any other expression of type T, and
>    a) ...
>    b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;
>    c) ...

You can remove the reference part by `std::remove_reference` or `std::decay`. e.g.

```
template<typename T,
        typename IN = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>().begin())>,
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                    ^
        typename FT = function<ostream&(ostream&, const IN&)>
        >
void func(ostream& ss, const T& v,
              FT op = [](ostream& os, const IN&v)->ostream&{ return os << v; }) {
    for (const auto& i: v) {
        std::invoke(op, ss, i);
    }
}
```